# Removed "disabled & ready only" attributes from html form elements before form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, disabled-input

I have a form that I have a stack of fields that have been set with read only and disabled using jquery such as follows:

```
$('.adminOnlyField').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
$('.adminOnlyField').attr("readonly","true");
```

I'm using both so the select fields also look read only to the viewer.

I want to remove these attributes from the form before it is submitted so the other non-disabled fields will go though to my model. I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$('.clear_ready_only').click(function(e) 
{
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.adminOnlyField').removeAttr('disabled');
   $('.adminOnlyField').removeAttr('readonly');
   $('#CardModifysaleForm').submit();
});
```

Am I missing something? I thought this would have done the job?

Thanks

// FULL JS FUNCTIONALITY AFTER BELOW CHANGES

```
$(function () {

    var $adminOnly = $('.adminOnlyField');
    $adminOnly.prop('disabled',true).prop('readonly',true);
    $adminOnly.attr("onclick","return false");
    $adminOnly.attr("onkeydown","return false");
    $adminOnly.removeClass('required');
    $adminOnly.removeClass('date_picker');



    $('.clear_ready_only').click(function(e) 
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $adminOnly.prop('disabled',false).prop('readonly',false);
        $adminOnly.attr("onclick","return true");
        $adminOnly.attr("onkeydown","return true");
        $('#CardModifysaleForm').submit();
    });

});
```

Comment: disabled fields are not submitted, so why don't you just let it be?

Comment: The non-disabled fields are also not coming through into the model. The data sends though an empty array when any field is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) for both, which is faster than `.attr()`:

```
$('.adminOnlyField').prop('disabled',true);
$('.adminOnlyField').prop('readonly',true);
```

Second, for efficiency you should cache and chain:

```
var $adminOnly = $('.adminOnlyField');
$adminOnly.prop('disabled',true).prop('readonly',true);
```

And third, to answer your question, just flip the switches on submit:

```
$('.clear_ready_only').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $adminOnly.prop('disabled',false).prop('readonly',false);
    $('#CardModifysaleForm').submit();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I've made these changes however the data is still coming though as a blank array... Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: I've updated my post to show the full code as it stands with your changes, I tested the remove part by commenting out $('#CardModifysaleForm').submit(); the form fields seem to be disabled but the data sent though it still blank.. Thanks

Comment: u only provided information on enabling / disabling a button. if u want assistance with the submission of information from certain fields, provide the HTML of the form and the call that submits those fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.adminOnlyField').
   prop('disabled', false).
   prop('readonly', false);
```

Should do it.